# Realtek RTL8723BU on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: wireless

I've bought a laptop with Realtek rtl8723bu wifi adapter. Wifi works slowly and with weak signal compared to windows. I've search on the net and there are some solutions that download a driver from github, but none of them worked for me (I get an error since the fist step). What could I do? Thanks a lot.

I've followed these steps:

1st Step:

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

2nd Step:

```
sudo -i
echo blacklist rtl8xxxu >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

This ensured that the old driver was not be used for my device. In my case the problematic driver was rtl8xxxu. So I black listed it.

3rd Step: Now I disabled a line in the makefile of the new driver, because without this hack, two instances of the wireless chipset was shown in Network Manager

```
cd rtl8723bu
nano Makefile
```

Go down to line 21 and change this line:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

To comment it out, like this:

```
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

4th Step: Now build and install the driver:

```
source dkms.conf
sudo mkdir /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo cp -r core hal include os_dep platform dkms.conf Makefile rtl8723b_fw.bin /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms add $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
```

5th Step: Finally, install the compiled module with this command:

```
make
sudo make install
```

But I can't dkms fail on fist step. Also I wonder if that's a secure thing to do.

Comment: You need to post the steps you are trying and errors that you get.

Comment: You can't do `make install` and `dkms` at the same time. And what do you mean by "dkms fail on fist step"?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. No build errors.
Tested it in VM with Ubuntu 18.04LTS.
I did all steps except `make` and `make install`, which are not needed and **must not** be done with DKMS.

`make` + `make install` are for **manual** installation only if you do not use DKMS. Then you have to do `make` + `make install` every time you install new kernel or you have no driver with your new kernel. That is why DKMS was inveted - so you do not have to. Everything is automatic with DKMS.

My build log, no errors:

```
$ sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-70-generic -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40/build............
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

rtl8723bu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
```

If you did `make install`, then you have to clean it up before trying again.
Try that (replace /path/to with real path):

```
cd /path/to/rtl8723bu
sudo make uninstall
```

And then try again without `make` and `make install`
If you have not done anything else then you probably only need those two lines from 4th step:

```
source dkms.conf
sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
```